# How to get an array to display all its values at once

Tags: vb.net, arrays, loops

Here is some sample code:

```
Dim arrValue(3) as Integer
arrValue(0) = 5
arrValue(1) = 4
arrValue(2) = 7
arrValue(3) = 1
```

How can I display those four values next to each other.

More specifically, given those values how can I make txtValue.Text = 5471

**Edit:**

The idea I had would be to use some sort of function to append each one to the end using a loop like this:

```
Dim finalValue
For i As Integer = 3 To 0 Step -1
    arrValue(i).appendTo.finalValue
Next
```

Obviously that code wouldn't work though the premise is sound I don't know the syntax for appending things and I'm sure I wouldn't be able to append an Integer anyway, I would need to convert each individual value to a string first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another method is to use String.Join:

```
Sub Main
    Dim arrValue(3) as Integer
    arrValue(0) = 5
    arrValue(1) = 4
    arrValue(2) = 7
    arrValue(3) = 1

    Dim result As String = String.Join("", arrValue)

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way I can reverse the direction in which it joins? It builds the string from arrValue(0) up, but I want it to write from the top down to arrValue(0). In other words, using this method, it returns 001 when I want it to return 100. How do I fix that?

Comment: Old Post, but maybe useful to someone else - RE: how to get the opposite order of output, you could use Array.Reverse(arrValue) to reverse the order of values in the array

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integers to strings, and concatenate them:

```
Dim result as String = ""
For Each value as Integer in arrValue
  result += value.ToString()
Next
```

Note: using `+=` to concatenate strings performs badly if you have many strings. Then you should use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
Dim builder as New StringBuilder()
For Each value as Integer in arrValue
  builder.Append(value)
Next
Dim result as String = builder.ToString()
```

Comment: Stringbuilder sounds like what I need but I don't know what it is or how to use it. I need an example of how it would work in the case listed above.

Comment: @MarkKramer: I added an example above.

Comment: VB.net doesn't recognize StringBuilder at all. Both your example and the other one posted in relation to StringBuilder returned build errors

Comment: You just haven't imported the namespace where the `StringBuilder` class is. Use `System.Text.StringBuilder`, or import the `System.Text` namespace.

Comment: Well for future reference that's the kind of thing that should be included in your answer =p

Comment: @MarkKramer: That's not a thing that you can include in every answer. Some things have to be assumed, just like I assume stuff like that you know how to copy a piece of code and paste it at the right place in your code, and that you can adjust the code to your needs for example by renaming variables.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use StringBuilder to append the values together.

```
Dim finalValue as StringBuilder
finalValue = new StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 3 To 0 Step -1
    finalValue.Append(arrValue(i))
Next
```

Then just return the `finalValue.ToString()`

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to do some testing with this and see what I can do. Thanks! If it works I'll upvote and accept your answer

Comment: VB.net doesn't recognize StringBuilder at all. Both your example and the other one posted in relation to StringBuilder returned build errors.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to add `Imports System.Text`

Comment: to where? Does that go in Declarations?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = lbound(arrValue) to ubound(arrValue)
ss=ss & arrValue(i)
next i
end for 
debug.print ss
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but it would be nicer to explain a little bit what your solution does, and also make use of the code block formating in order to produce more readable text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26177605)

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim value as string = ""


For A As Integer = 1 To Begin.nOfMarks
   value += "Mark " & A & ": " & (Begin.Marks(A)) & vbCrLf 
Next A
```